# How to exclude weekends in field update logic?

Tags: apex

If the expected drawdown date is Today and next three days then making ET_Urgency_flag__c is TRUE but i wanted to add logic to exclude weekends Can any one help here ?

```
  public static void updateUrgencyFlag(Map<Id,Case> newCaseMap,Map<Id,Case> oldCaseMap){
    system.debug('start---->');
    for(Case caseRec: newCaseMap.values()){
        if(caseRec.ET_Expected_Drrwadown_Date__c <= System.today().addDays(4) && caseRec.ET_Expected_Drrwadown_Date__c >= System.today()){

            caseRec.ET_Urgency_flag__c = TRUE;
            
        }else{
            caseRec.ET_Urgency_flag__c = FALSE;
        }            
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using [Business Hours](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_classes_businesshours.htm)?

Comment: Hi @PhilW, No actually How to use that can you give it an example please ? are you suggesting formula filed for this logic ?

Comment: An internet search like "using salesforce business hours in apex" will give you plenty of things to read through. I am not suggesting a formula field. It's important that you demonstrate willingness to research things for yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [BusinessHours](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_classes_businesshours.htm) class, which provides methods to calculate the working hours and days for an organization. You can use the `isWithin()` method to check if a given date and time are within the business hours of a specified business hours record.

You can modify your code like this:

```
public static void updateUrgencyFlag(Map<Id,Case> newCaseMap,Map<Id,Case> oldCaseMap){
        Id businessHoursId = [SELECT Id FROM BusinessHours WHERE IsDefault = true].Id;
        for (Case caseRec: newCaseMap.values()) {
                Datetime expectedDrawdown = caseRec.ET_Expected_Drrwadown_Date__c;
                if (expectedDrawdown <= System.now().addDays(4) && expectedDrawdown >= System.now() && BusinessHours.isWithin(businessHoursId, expectedDrawdown)) {
                        caseRec.ET_Urgency_flag__c = TRUE;
                } else {
                        caseRec.ET_Urgency_flag__c = FALSE;
                }
        }
}
```

This code will only set the `ET_Urgency_flag__c` to **true** if the expected drawdown date and time are within the next four working days and hours.

Answer (score 0):

There is 'format' method that would help in your case but it will work with datetime only. So in your case you can use "System.now().format('E')", it will give you 3 letter day name ex: Sun, Mon, Tue etc.

You can try this code as well.

```
if(System.now().format('E') != 'Sun' && System.now().format('E') != 'Sat') {
    System.debug(true);
}
else {
    System.debug(false);
}
```

In your code you just need to include "(System.now().format('E') != 'Sun' && System.now().format('E') != 'Sat')".

There is another format option i.e. format('u') which gives you day number of the week. ex: 7 for Sunday, 1 for Monday, 2 for Tuesday etc.